# What does test_idx mean?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been going through a tutorial on scikit-learn and I came across this variable `test_idx`. I am unable to find a definition for it. I've Googled too but zero results. It looks like a standard variable used in tutorials but no explanation was given.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
test_idx = [0, 50, 100]

# Training Data
training_labels = np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
training_data = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of **test** **i**n**d**e**x**es to drop from training data, that will probably be used to build test data, too.

Let's say we want to explicitly build the three relevant sets of indices for this machine learning problem:

```py
idx = range(len(iris.data))  # Set of indices for the whole dataset
test_idx = [0, 50, 100]      # Choose 3 of them, arbitrarily, that will help
                             # build a test set
train_idx = [i for i in idx if i not in test_idx]  # Create the list of all other indices, 
                                                   # that will help build a training set
```

Now that you know the indices of the rows you want to use for the training and test parts of your dataset, you can either build these parts in a constructive or destructive way:

- Constructive

```py
training_data_1 = iris.data[train_idx]
training_labels_1 = iris.target[train_idx]
test_data_1 = iris.data[test_idx]
test_labels_1 = iris.target[test_idx]
```

- Destructive

```py
training_data_2 = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis=0)
training_labels_2 = np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
test_data_2 = np.delete(iris.data, train_idx, axis=0)
test_labels_2 = np.delete(iris.target, train_idx)
```

As a "real world" example, the `split()` method from class [`GroupShuffleSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html) returns two arrays which are training indexes and test indexes within the splitted dataset.